# How to design a dynamic progress bar with stages and scalable input with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a progressive bar for fund raising activities. The minimum value is the value for the activity to take place and the maximum value is the max fund it can take. It will be the best if the color of progressive bar to be red before it reaches minimum marker and it turns into green afterwards.

This is what I have in mind for progress bar 
http://www.icondeposit.com/local--files/imageid:268/UI-Progress-Bars.jpg

This is what I have achieved so far 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4nn64bdu8cuzch/progress%20bar.tiff

Here is the code of my html

```
<div ng-controller="ProgressDemoCtrl">
    <h3>Dynamic </h3>
    <progressbar max="max" value="dynamic"><span style="color:black; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / \
{{max}}</span></progressbar>
<!--scalable input -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crd_volume">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="update()">Confirm the volume</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```

And here is my code for controller:

```
var ProgressDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {

  $scope.max = 200;
  $scope.min = 100;
  var value=0;
  var max_volume=$scope.max
  var volume=1;

  $scope.update=function(){
  volume=document.getElementById("crd_volume").value;
  alert(volume);

  if (((value+parseFloat(volume))<max_volume)||((value+parseFloat(volume))==max_volume))
      {
          value =parseFloat(value)+parseFloat(volume);
       }
    $scope.dynamic = value;
    $scope.type = type;
  }
```

Lastly, I tried my code in plunker. But it does not work there, even though I added a ng-app and ng-controller.

Really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the link to the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dhBvWBIXDzZdnGBxPOSQ?p=preview

Comment: Your plunk doesn't work for several reasons but the most important is that you did not include Angular in the first place. For future reference with Plunker you can select an angular project from the new button dropdown and it will include some basic boiler plate for you. I am also assuming you are using the `angular-ui` progress bar directive, I will formulate an answer below on this assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption you are using the `ui.bootstrap.progressbar` directive, you can create a progress bar out of 2 bar directives. One to reach your activity value and another for the remainder of the progress, this allows you to style them separately.

You can see a working **[plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Tvx1pKQqV0bVFkr8KvK?p=preview)** but the basic HTML becomes:

```
<progress>
    <bar value="bar1.value" type="{{bar1.type}}"></bar>
    <bar value="bar2.value" type="{{bar2.type}}"></bar>
</progress>

<input ng-model="volume">
<button ng-click="confirmVolume()">Confirm</button>
```

Then in your controller set the values (and the type if it is dynamic). We will do this calling a function via the `ng-click` directive as per your example as below:

```
$scope.confirmVolume = function () {
    var units = $scope.bar2.max / 100;
    $scope.bar1.value = $scope.volume < 100 ? $scope.volume/units : 100/units;
    $scope.bar2.value = $scope.volume > 100 ? ($scope.volume - 100)/units : 0;
};
```

Note that I have used units here simply to convert the volume into a percentage (the max value of the progress bar is 100, in your example it is 200, hence each percentage point would be 2 units).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't give you an answer here just this link, i rebuilt your examle and this is a sketch of what you might want. basically you had the idea just don't access dom in controllers doing things like

```
  document.getElementById('id').value.
```

in the controller. besides being gains separation of concerns it will try to parce the dom tree 
searching for the element which is an unnecessary overhead. use scope variables inseta using ng-model binding like this

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crd_volume" ng-model="volume">
```

anyway here is the full exmaple, some details need to be addressed since i don't know all the logic you want t put in place. but this should be enought to get you on the right track.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nch1UYO6Et6HNfXm0Qhd?p=preview